# How can I compare a UTC timestamp date to the current date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs, utc

I have a UTC timestamp that I need to compare with the current date. The current date is the date.. not the hour or the second. Just the date

So I need to compare a UTC stamp to that in Javascript. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: In what format is that timestamp? Integer milliseconds since epoch?

Answer (score 0):

The Date type in javascript has the getTime() method witch returns the milliseconds since 1/1/1970. So is you get the time from both dates you can compare them.

```
var dDate = new Date();
var iMilSecs = dDate.getTime();
```

Comment: This is good but not fully there. I don't want to compare the exact date up to the millisecond. I just want to compare the days? The utc stamp that I'm comparing with is up to the millisecond, however

Comment: So you want to say that there are n days diff between the two dates? Could you provide the question with an example?

Comment: If i understand your problem correctly you can just construct dates with new Date() or new Date(millis) and then you can just call setHours(0), setMinutes(0) and so on.. on that date: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp And then you can compare just against the preceding midnight...